# Is this selfmade wordplay solvable and strong enough?

Tags: word

Here is a question I have created myself and I want to use it in a self-created game. But I want to check if others can solve it. It is designed to be a little bit challenging.

> I am standing around
>   All night All day
>   Have multiple guys in me
>   forever they will stay
>   no possibility to say
>   "Please go away"
>   Some of them sometimes leave for a while
>   But they are back by no later than closing time
>   The guys can be used for drawing
>   Do you know my name?

EDIT:

Maybe the `closing time`-part is confusing. The closing time for a office is meant.

Edit2 :
Maybe this could help:
[image]

Comment: I'm confused now, it can't be the office workers cause there are out and not back by closing time.

Comment: no, no humans ;) and you nearly made it with the "box". But it isn't a box ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @RadoslavHristov's answer.

You're a

> Pen/Pencil holder

Im standing around
All night All day

> You are, on your desk for example

Have multiple guys in me

> Refers to the pens/pencils

forever they will stay
no possibility to say
"Please go away"

> Obviously, they don't speak

Some of them sometimes leave for a while

> They are used to write

But they are back by no later than closing time

> We always put them back in their place

The guys can be used for drawing

> Obvious when you're a pen!

Comment: thats it! Gratz ;)

Answer (score 4):

I know it might sound silly but it looks to me like

> Box of colour pencils (or pens or markers)

Im standing around

> The box is right there on my desk

All night All day

> Yep, all the time

Have multiple guys in me

> It has different coloured pens in it

forever they will stay

> Yes, they are doomed to stay in there

no possibility to say
"Please go away"

> The box has really no say in this

Some of them sometimes leave for a while

> You take out a pen/marker/pencil for a while

But they are back by no later than closing time

> And then put it back before closing the box

The guys can be used for drawing

> And you can draw it them.

do you know my name?

Comment: oh my god :D you nearly made it. Please re-think the standing part. Is a box really in a standing state by nature? Or could there be a another thing?

Comment: Could be one of these "cups" to put pencils/pens in?