# Selfmade wordplay puzzle Part 2

Tags: word, wordplay

Here is another selfmade wording puzzle for you guys. This puzzle is also for a selfmade game and also needs to be challenging. It is easier than the [previous one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/40682/is-this-selfmade-wordplay-solvable-and-strong-enough).

> You have never seen us
>   You obviously haven't smelled us
>   We are very small
>   But for the smallest atom we are tall
>   We can't fly
>   We are very easy to identify
>   Have been told in many stories
>   But to be kind is not mandatory
>   We have brothers in Ireland
>   Of playing football we are fans

Comment: Based on your previous answer its probably something solid

Comment: what is the meaning of "solid" in your case?

Comment: Football?? Is it american football or the real one??

Comment: just football ;)

Comment: @Snickbrack like an inanimate object - like a pen holder from your last one

Comment: yes, then it is a solid thing in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, but is it possibly a

> Leprechaun

You have never seen us

> leprechauns are myths, cannot be seen

You obviously haven't smelled us

> See above

We are very small
But for the smallest atom we are tall

> Leprechauns are notably small creatures, but not as small as an atom

We can't fly

> Self-explanatory, leprechauns can't fly.

We are very easy to identify

> Leprechauns are always small wearing green clothes.

Have been told in many stories

> A popular folklore myth

But to be kind is not mandatory

> They are not known to be nice

We have brothers in Ireland

> Leprechauns are Irish

Of playing football we are fans

> Possibly a reference to the [Fighting Irish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notre_Dame_Fighting_Irish#Football)

Comment: This only fits a couple of clues

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil See my edit

Comment: correct answer dude! you are a Answer-Champion! you showed me that this question seems to be a good choice tho!

Comment: I would be wary with the last statement though, depending on how widespread you want your game to be. I am not sure how many people globally know of the Fighting Irish

Comment: If they know Leprechaun's then they should also know the fighting ones. If not then they should start searching in a pub like the pokemon-girlies...

Answer (score 2):

Possibly too abstract but:

> Thoughts

You have never seen us

> You can't see thoughts

You obviously haven't smelled us

> :| ... Obviously

We are very small

> Limited to the space of our minds

But for the smallest atom we are tall

> Anything compared to an atom is big

We can't fly

> No, they can't

We are very easy to identify

> You can very easily identify a thought

Have been told in many stories

> Not sure but possibly: "I'm having a thought," **thought** BeastlyGerbil

But to be kind is not mandatory

> You can have thoughts which aren't nice

We have brothers in Ireland

> Working on it...

Of playing football we are fans

> Not sure

Comment: that is something I haven't 'thought' about :D it could be an answer but it is PartyHatPanda's answer... But yours is a solid answer and will definitly make it into my game ;) will leave you Credits!